# How to integrate over a set of data?

Tags: numerical-integration

The Hamiltonian of a system is $H = 0.5p^2  + 0.5x^2 + 0.1x^4$. I have obtained the equations of motion. To solve them (numerically) I need to specify $x_0$ and $p_0$. But then the question asks me to compute 
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_0\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dp_0e^{-{\beta}H(x_0,p_0)}x_0x(t)$. 
Since $x(t)$ depends on the values of $x_0$ and $p_0$ that I specify, I have to integrate then over a list of data. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure that this is what you're trying to do, but if I do then here is my suggestion:

I assume the equations of motion are $\dot x=p$ and $\dot p=-x-\frac{2}{5}x^3$. With these equations, the value of $e^{-\beta H}x(0)x(T)$ can be obtained using `ParametricNDSolveValue` as follows:

```
TMAX=10;
fun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == p[t], 
   p'[t] == -x[t] - 2/5 x[t]^3, x[0] == x0, p[0] == p0}, 
   Exp[-β (1/2 (p[T]^2 + x[T]^2) + 1/10 x[T]^4)] x[T], 
   {t, 0, TMAX}, {x0, p0}];
```

To get the value of $e^{-\beta H}x(0)x(T)$ for $x_0=1,p_0=2$ and $t=3$ you simply evaluate `fun[1,2,3]`. Note, however, that this is done by numerically solving the equations from `t=0` to `TMAX` so `fun` can not be evaluated for `t>TMAX` (technically it does return a value, but it's an extrapolation and you shouldn't use that).

Then you can simply integrate. For example, to get the answer at $t=2$ and $\beta=1$ you can run

```
Block[{β = 1}, 
   NIntegrate[fun[x0, p0, 2], {x0, -∞,∞}, {p0, -∞,∞}]
]
```

**Edit:**

Now I see that you want the Hamiltonian to be evaluated at $x_0,p_0$, so you can use a simpler code. You replace `fun` by

```
fun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{x'[t] == p[t], 
  p'[t] == -x[t] - 2/5 x[t]^3, x[0] == x0, p[0] == p0}, 
  x[T], {t, 0, TMAX}, {x0, p0, T}]
```

and you can set up a function to calculate the correlation like this:

```
corr[β_, t_]:= NIntegrate[
    Exp[-β (1/2 (p0^2 + x0^2) + 1/10 x0^4)] x0 fun[x0, p0,t], 
    {x0, -∞,∞}, {p0, -∞,∞}]
```

Comment: Thank you. This works great. I didn't know I could get a numerical solution with parameters before.